# Mongod running while systems writes into the database

Tags: mongodb

Does mongod lock the database in case I am using it from the command line and the system due to external effects wants to write into the database?

Comment: what do you mean by "the system"?

Comment: I mean I am monitoring how the database gets filled in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB has a reader/writer lock protecting access to each database. Any thread that performs a write on the database (insert, update, delete, ensureIndex, drop(), dropIndexes(), etc...) will grab a write lock for the operation (with possible yielding in case I/O is about to happen). Queries (find(), count(), aggregation) will grab a read lock.